# Yii: Blocks of required form data

Tags: php, forms, yii, cactiverecord

Trying to figure out a decent approach here...

I have a form,  where based on if a user selects a drop down in the form or not,  it shows or hides a few other form fields.  If the form fields are visible I want them to be required.  If they are not visible,  I do not want them to be required.

I'm trying to figure out an approach for handling this inside my model rules - I tried something like this in my model rules() function:

```
$requiredFields = 'cashAtClosing, offerPrice, closingDate, financingType,surveyDays,'.
        'earnestMoney, escrowAgent, escrowAgentAddress, surveyProvider, surveyDays, titlePolicyPayment,'.
        'titleObjectionDays, titleCompany, titleCompanyAddress, optionFee, optionDays, optionCredit';

    if ($this->financingType == "THIRDPARTYFINANCE")
    {
        Yii::trace("Add Financing Type Rules");
        $requiredFields .= ',creditApprovalRequired,creditApprovalDays,loan1Amount, loan1DueInFullYears, '.
        'loan1InterestNotToExceed, loan1InterestNotToExceedYears, loan1OriginationNotToExceed';

    }
    else
    {
       $safeFields .= ',creditApprovalRequired,creditApprovalDays,loan1Amount, loan1DueInFullYears, '.
        'loan1InterestNotToExceed, loan1InterestNotToExceedYears, loan1OriginationNotToExceed';
    }

    array_push($rulesArray, array($requiredFields, 'required'));
```

problem is that it seems that the rules function is called prior to the model being populated so in my example here $this->financingType is always empty so this code doesn't wok.

Whats a better approach here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add this code to beforeValidate() method of your model. It's should help you.

But create $rulesArray property in your model. Add new rules to this variable via $this->rulesArray in beforeValidate() method and use this variable in your rules() method.